# Task 415 (virtual:native:/home/user/Yocto/Poky/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/automake/automake_1.15.bb, do_compile) failed with exit code '1'

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to build an image with yocto, I did everything according instructions from https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/yocto-project-qs/yocto-project-qs.html

I've already done the pre-configuration

```
 $ git clone http://git.yoctoproject.org/git/poky
 $ cd poky
 $ git checkout -b fido origin/fido
 $ source oe-init-build-env
```

and I get the following errors when running : `bitbake -k core-image-sato`

```
ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at 
/home/user/Yocto/Poky/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake- 
native/1.15-r0/temp/log.do_compile.2660)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: 
/home/user/Yocto/Poky/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake- 
native/1.15-r0/temp/log.do_compile.2660
ERROR: Task 415 
(virtual:native:/home/user/Yocto/Poky/poky/meta/recipes- 
devtools/automake/automake_1.15.bb, do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is a particular reason, you want to use fido I will recommend using the more recent releases like sumo or rocko at least. You might also want to take a look at something like [yoe-distro](https://github.com/YoeDistro/yoe-distro) which also allows to build in a Docker environment and thus not requiring a downgrade of OS to something which Yocto/OpenEmbedded might require.

Comment: Good answer here - I was also trying to follow some online article. I did realise it was old when I looked at the release (jethro). I also had the exact same error. I updated to `sumo` as suggested and it has got alot further (and still building).  I think next I will try `warrior`. I am trying to build for BeagleBB so I'll what is that latest that supports. It seems important to look at the **date** of some of these articles! Mine was from 2016. Here is one from 2019: `https://jumpnowtek.com/beaglebone/BeagleBone-Systems-with-Yocto.html` - might ne useful for the next person : )

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are building an old release (1.8), its important that a tested distribution is used on build host. There are 
[here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#detailed-supported-distros) Please make sure that your host distro is among the one in this list

Comment: If I have Ubuntu 18.04.1 on my host, which release will be most suitable? Thud?

Comment: may be Ubuntu 14.04 or Ubuntu 14.10 if you use ubuntu distro.